# Deleting file from s3 using pycharm boto3 library

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

How can I delete file with particular extension from s3 bucket using pycharm boto3 library.
For example I have an s3 bucket having multiple files with different extension like '.txt' , '.csv' etc.
I want to create python script which will delete file from s3 having ".csv" extension only
Please help

Comment: Use [list_objects_v2](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects_v2), with a [paginator](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/paginators.html) to list objects, decide which objects match your criteria, then call [delete_objects](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.delete_objects) to remove them.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a trigger on your S3 bucket with a suffix value as ".csv" to invoke a lambda where you can read the bucket and key from the event and use boto3's delete() method to delete the CSV file.

`import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3.Object('your-bucket', 'your-key').delete()`

Comment: I didn't want to edit your answer directly, but surround your code with `\`\`\`` to create a multiline code block. Alternatively, highlight your code in the editor and hit the `{}` button.